# imageview-cropping not working

Tags: android, imageview, crop

My imageview does not change when I try either "centerCrop" or "center." What is the issue to solve so that I can crop the image?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="xx.myapplication.MainActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/party"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="From. h"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#FFEBEE"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Happy Wednesday!!"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Image that I see with my code:

[image: Image that I see with my code now is here<<]

Comment: Always inline images by prefixing an "!" before the image link so that others can view it without having to open a link.

Comment: @EvilTak Are you saying if I put "!" before the image link, it would show up the image directly on this page instead of asking the viewer to click on it?

Comment: Yes I am. Take a look at my [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47440001/revisions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `src` instead of `background`

```
android:src="@drawable/party"
```